# How to set a variable equal to a month and day, and then do math with it?

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe

I'm working in Python with a pandas dataframe. The dataframe contains 4 columns. The columns I'm working with here are year and harvest. Year is the year a specific event happened, and harvest is the number of days before August 31 that the event occurred. So basically, if harvest is equal to 23, then the event occurred on September 23 of that year.

I'm being asked to find when, specifically, the earlier harvest in the dataset occurred. For reference, my dataframe is titled "MyData". So I first defined the earliest year, as so:

```
Earliest = MyData.loc[MyData['year'].idxmin()]
```

Now I'm not sure how to use the 'harvest' variable to return a specific date (with just months and days).

I'm tried to define a Base Date variable of 8/31, and then just adding the 'harvest' variable from that base date. This is the line I have right now:

```
BaseDate = pd.to_datetime("08/31",format="%m/%d")
```

That's returning way more than I want it to, though. I simply want it to return 08/31. Then, I would use that BaseDate variable to do something like this:

```
print("The harvest happened on", BaseDate + pd.DateOffset(days=Earliest['harvest']),"of that year.")
```

And it should return something like "The harvest happened on 08/16 of that year."

Instead, it is current returning the following: "The harvest happened on 1900-09-23 00:00:00 of that year."

It would probably be better for me to create a whole new column in the data frame that does this math for every row. I'm open to a solution that does that, and would actually prefer it! But for now, the way I presented it would suffice.

When I try to make a new column, I write it out as follows:

```
MyData['Date'] = datetime.datetime(2000,8,31) + MyData['harvest']
```

or

```
MyData['Date'] = BaseDate + MyData['harvest']
```

But it returns this error: "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.datetime' and 'float'"

Comment: I suppose another (much simpler) way to ask this question would be, how can I add a column to this data frame entitled "date" that would just add 'harvest' to 08/31.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `(BaseDate + pd.DateOffset(days=Earliest['harvest'])).strftime('%m/%d')`

**Updated**
This works

chk['newColumn2'] = BaseDate + pd.to_timedelta(chk['harvest'],unit='d')

I took example as

```
>>> chk = pd.DataFrame({'year':[1700,1701,1702,1703],
...                     'harvest':[42.5,35.9,45.0,49.4]})
>>> 
>>> chk['date']= pd.to_datetime(chk['year'],format='%Y') 
>>> chk['newColumn'] = chk['date'] + pd.to_timedelta(chk['harvest'],unit='d')
>>> chk
   harvest  year                date           newColumn
0     42.5  1700 1700-01-01 00:00:00 1700-02-12 12:00:00
1     35.9  1701 1701-01-01 00:00:00 1701-02-05 21:36:00
2     45.0  1702 1702-01-01 00:00:00 1702-02-15 00:00:00
3     49.4  1703 1703-01-01 00:00:00 1703-02-19 09:36:00
```

Using our BaseDate we could also perform

```
>>> BaseDate = pd.to_datetime("08/31",format="%m/%d")
>>> chk['newColumn2'] = BaseDate + pd.to_timedelta(chk['harvest'],unit='d')
>>> chk
   harvest  year                date           newColumn          newColumn2
0     42.5  1700 1700-01-01 00:00:00 1700-02-12 12:00:00 1900-10-12 12:00:00
1     35.9  1701 1701-01-01 00:00:00 1701-02-05 21:36:00 1900-10-05 21:36:00
2     45.0  1702 1702-01-01 00:00:00 1702-02-15 00:00:00 1900-10-15 00:00:00
3     49.4  1703 1703-01-01 00:00:00 1703-02-19 09:36:00 1900-10-19 09:36:00
```

Comment: Any idea of how to add a new column to the dataframe of dates in this format?

Comment: That you could do just by MyData['newColumn'] = (BaseDate + pd.DateOffset(days=Earliest['harvest'])).strftime('%m/%d')

Comment: I'm getting the error "unsupported type for timedelta days component: Series"

Comment: @CornelWestside for which line we are not using,
could you attach code snippet

Comment: What's output of MyData['harvest']
is it float ? 
it should be date

Comment: MyData['harvest'] is a series. But each individual value is a float. For example, type(MyData['harvest'][3]) returns numpy.float64

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190643/discussion-between-vikrant-pawar-and-cornel-westside).